# Get session by id in ajax call

Tags: java, ajax, session, request

Is there a way to have access to session in a AJAX call made to a JAVA server.

On the server, the `request` object has both the `session` and `cookies` properties `NULL`.

I can pass though the session id as a parameter, but how can I access the session by ID?

Edit

Using `session.getSession(false);` returns `null`, while `session.getSession(true);` obviously returns a new session, with another id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to deal with this is to append ";jsessionid=" at the end of the url. For instance, in a jsp:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
...
    xhr.open("GET", url + ";jsessionid=<%=pageContext.getSession().getId()%>"); 
...
</script>
```

The line:

```
xhr.open("GET", url + ";jsessionid=<%=pageContext.getSession().getId()%>");
```

is rendered as:

```
xhr.open("GET", url + ";jsessionid=6EBA4F94838796DC6D653DCA1DD06373");
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, I now have the following issue: the string is sent as you wrote ";jsessionid=<%=pageContext.session.id%>" instead of computing the session id and having something like ";jsessionid=__sessionid__"

Comment: Actually, the scriplet should be <%=pageContext.getSession().getId()%>.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you don't have a session!

Make sure when the load containing the AJAX script, the session is created on the server.

```
session.getSession(true);
```

If this is stored as a cookie, then your AJAX call will submit it back to the server when it fires.

Comment: If I use `session.getSession(true);` then a new session is created, with a different id, I would like restore the existing session on the server for the visitor. Maybe if I pass the session id as a parameter helps.

Answer (score 0):

In order to access the session you do not need the session id. This is all done for you behind the scenes by your servlet container. To get the session for a particluar request all you need to do is:

```
 HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
```

where `request` is your `HttpServletRequest`. The `false` arg means "do not create session if it does not exist". Of course use "true" if you want the session to be created if it doesn't exist.

Comment: I've edited my question. I was already doing what you said, but, unfortunately, it is not working.