# Getting Session data in Ajax call

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, session, jakarta-ee

hi I am querying database to load all items based on some criteria and setting this result in session as

```
data = service.getData();
session.setAttribute("data", data);
```

now I am trying to access this data via an Ajax call and my Ajax call is served by a different servlet rather then which fetched the data from DB.

Ajax call using jquery

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/com/tp/AjaxXML.jsp",
    data: ({cmd: "report"}),
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
        $(xml).find('site').each(function(){
            var url = $(this).attr('url');                                  
        });
    }
});
```

in my AjaxXML.jsp

I am doing

```
if("report".equals(cmd)){
    List<Object> data = (List<Object>)request.getSession().getAttribute("data");

    if(data == null){
        System.out.println("data is null ");
    }
}
```

every time I am getting the data as null via the Ajax call how ever I try to access the session data normally from my first servlet it works.

could someone let me know if I am doing something wrong?

I noticed one more thing when we do `session.getId();` and `pageContext.getSession().getId();`
both of them are returning different Id's? Is this expected to me they should be same anyone differ on that?

Comment: You need to show more codes that surround both lines of codes you have posted.

Comment: @gurung i think rest of the code is irrelevant i just want to know whether we can access the data set in session via a ajax call?

Comment: Try with `request.getSession(false)` in the second case.

Comment: You might want to check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619277/get-session-by-id-in-ajax-call

Comment: this is still not working with request.getSession(false), the link refers to Php however m facing this problem in J2EE

Comment: See if the sessionid (should be jsessionid...) is also sent with the request using something like firebug.

Comment: its set in the cookie JSESSIONID=AAE75FA4060A5789AD22C0E65C60141B and is sent along with the request;

Comment: @gurung: trying `request.getSession(false)` is nonsense. It'll return `null` if session doesn't exist.

Comment: @BalusC: Yes, I was just trying to see if in case the session created by the first servlet was somehow destroyed. And that would mean the second servlet was also creating a new session.

Answer (score 1):

> *I noticed one more thing when we do `session.getId();` and `pageContext.getSession().getId();` both of them are returning different Id's? Is this expected to me they should be same anyone differ on that?*

No, they should definitely not differ. I however assume that you have examined them within the **same** request. If you examined them in *different* requests, then the difference can be explained by the absence of the proper JSESSIONID cookie. Cookies are domain and context specific. You're apparently sending the ajax request to a different domain/context. The leading slash `/` in the ajax URL also confirms this less or more. Make sure that you're sending it to the **same** domain/context. Use a context-relative URL, something like as `url: "AjaxXML.jsp"` and move the code to the same domain/context, or turn on session sharing between different contexts at server level.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, doing the Ajax response handling in a JSP is a bad idea. Rather do it in a servlet.

Replace

```
url: "/com/tp/AjaxXML.jsp",
```

by

```
url: "/com/tp/AjaxXML",
```

and put the code in `doPost()` method of the servlet which is mapped on that URL pattern.

#### See also:

- [How to use Servlets and Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/how-to-use-servlets-and-ajax)